# Query Restriction

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please tell me what is the issue with this code.
Basically what I am trying to do is to identify the renter based on their IDs rather than names (in case there are more renters with the same name). Thank you

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PROPERTYId, P.PROPERTYName, T.TYPEName 
FROM RENTAL R, PROPERTY P, TYPE T
Group by P.PROPERTYId, P.PROPERTYName, T.TYPEName 
HAVING RENTERId = (SELECT RENTERId FROM RENTER
WHERE RENTERFirstName = 'AL'
AND RENTERLastName = 'SMITH')
AND R.PROPERTYId = P.PROPERTYId
AND P.TYPEId = T.TYPEId
AND T.TYPEName = 'VILLA';
```

Comment: Please provide some sample output or error messages.

Comment: Nitpick - I would rather see proper inner joins instead of the cross join that is reduced in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     Renter.RenterID, 
     Property.PropertyId, 
     Property.PropertyName, 
     Type.TYPEName  
FROM Rental
    inner join Property on Rental.PropertyID = Property.PropertyID
    inner join Type on Property.TypeID = Type.TypeID
    inner join Renter on Rental.RenterID = Renter.RenterID
where Type.TypeName = 'villa'
and Renter.RenterFirstName = 'al'
and Renter.RenterLastName = 'smith'
```

Note how the tables are linked using the `join` syntax, and the `where` clause is reserved for filtering.

Comment: You seem to have dropped the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yes. There's no aggregations, so distinct will work just as well

Comment: Thanks podiluska, but I dont think the query will work, I am still gon have more than one renter with the same name if therr are any

Comment: That's why I included the renter ID in the results.

Comment: Yes, the renterID was the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try it .  Replace  =  by  IN .